# Change of variables in Heat Equation's solution

Tags: integration

I can't get my head around this equality. Note that $0\le s\le t$
$$\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-t+s}^{x+t-s}f(y,s) dy ds=\frac{1}{2}\int_0^t\int_{x-s}^{x+s}f(y,t-s)dyds\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(x\in\mathbb{R},t\ge 0)$$

Comment: It seems you are a frequent user. Then why don't you use MathJax?

Comment: I'm sorry. Should I edit the question?

Comment: That's up to you. But generally, if the others see that you have put some efforts into your question, it is more likely that they would want to help you

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** (Thanks to @Swapnil Tripathi) Let $\sigma=t-s$, then $s=t-\sigma$ and
$$\begin{align}\int_0^t\int_{x-t+s}^{x+t-s}f(y,s)dyds&=-\int_{\sigma=t}^{\sigma=0}\int_{x-\sigma}^{x+\sigma}f(y,t-\sigma)dyd\sigma\\&=\int_{0}^{t}\int_{x-\sigma}^{x+\sigma}f(y,t-\sigma)dyd\sigma\end{align}$$

Comment: But $ds=-d\sigma$?

Comment: @user141561 Sorry. Will fix it now

Comment: @polfosol: Changing the variable makes $\sigma$ range from $t$ to $0$

Comment: @SwapnilTripathi Thank you for noticing that. I was sleepy last night and couldn't think straight!